# How to force IntelliJ editor to restrict line length?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a text file that looks like:

```
a=12
 b=13
 c=14
 d =15
 e = 16
 f = 17
```

Some of the numbers have spaces after them. Some don't. Some have tabs etc.

It seems that when i am in InteliJ's editor any place i click on is well .. clickable.

**How can i restrict it by actual line length?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Allow placement of caret after end of line`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the global code style to do things like put spaces around the assignment operator, and then do a global "reformat code" by selected text, file, or entire project.

I use IntelliJ 12:

[image]